# Using the keyboard, how can I copy a cell in a column to other rows based upon a neighboring columns row range?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have cells **(B10:B20)** populated with **anything** but an empty value.

In **C10**, I create a forumla **=+A10/2**.  With they keyboard, I want to copy the formula in **C10** down all the way to the last row in column **B**.

There used to be a way in old versions of excel to use the keyboard to do a **ctrl-c** then select the range of rows based upon a neighboring column .

Answer (score 0):

The way still working in Excel 2013 (and I think also above, but I can't test):

- after entering the formula press <kbd>left</kbd> to move to column B
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> - now you're at the last non-empty cell of column B
- press <kbd>right</kbd> - now you're in column C
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> selects the whole column including the formula
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> fills down the formula.